# uasort() Array was modified by the user comparison function

Tags: php

I have a class that is basically a wrapper to an Array and implements IteratorAggregate.
When a new object of the class is created, it stores it's value in a protected variable called $value. The value can be a string, integer, etc.. or a traversable object (like an array).

This object is "recursive" since when a traversable object (like an array) is passed to the constructor, he creates another instance of the class. Here's the constructor to clarify:

```
class ListItem implements \IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $readOnly = false;
    protected $key;
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($key, $value, $readOnly = false)
    {
        if($readOnly) $this->readOnly = true;
        if(is_numeric($key)) $key = 'index'.$key;
        $this->key = $key;

        if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Traversable) {
            $this->value = array();
            foreach($value as $k => $v) {
                if(is_numeric($k)) $k = 'index'.$k;
                $this->value[$k] =  new ListItem($k, $v, $readOnly);
            }
        } else {
            $this->value = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if ( is_array($this->value) ) {
            return 'ListItem OBJECT(' . count($this->value) . ')';
        } else {
            return $this->value;
        }
    }
```

---

Right now, I'm trying to write a simple sorting method for the class.

To sort by Key, this works like a charm:

```
$success = ksort($this->value, $comparison);
```

but to sort by value, asort does not work since the actual value I'm trying to sort is stored inside the value property.

So I tried using uasort, like this:

```
   $success = uasort($this->value, function ($a, $b)
   {                    
      if ($a->value == $b->value) return 0;
      else if($a->value < $b->value) return -1;
      else return 1;
   });
```

but for some unclear reason i get the following error:

> Warning: uasort() [function.uasort]: Array was modified by the user
>   comparison function in /* /* /* /ListItem.php on line 129

---

**Q. Why does this happen if I'm just accessing $value for comparison not actually changing anything?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a closure (or anonymous function) is in the global scope which means `uasort` could not access private or protected members of the `ListItem` object (although other `ListItem` Objects can access their sibling's private/protected properties)

this solved the problem: (casting to string)

```
$success = uasort($this->value, function ($objA, $objB) use ($comparison)
{
    $a = (string) $objA;
    $b = (string) $objB;
    if($comparison == ListItem::SORT_NUMERIC) {
        if (is_numeric($a)) $a = (int) $a;
        if (is_numeric($b)) $b = (int) $b;
    }                   
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    else if($a < $b) return -1;
    else return 1;
});
```